# How to read numbers of rows and columns and print in a specific way

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, read

I need to make a shell script that will receive a number of rows and a number of columns and then print a word as the number of rows and columns.
For example: 2 rows, 3 columns

expected output:

```
word word word 
word word word
```

I know how to use `read` but I don't know how to get the output.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work? Provide an example and any error messages. Add this to the question. Do not post it in the comments.

Comment: I don't know how to.. I don't know how to use the read strings to make this happen

Comment: you can check `for` loops in bash

Comment: You wrote "I know how to use `read` but I don't know how to get the output". Then, please, show your code with the parts you know and use comments instead of real code for the parts you don't know how to implement. Please also show better examples of both input and corresponding output.

Comment: `echo "How many rows?" ; read row ; echo "How many columns?" ; read column`  now my problem is that no matter what I tried I could not get the word I want to print the way I mentioned above, with the number of rows and columns I get from `read` .

Comment: As I previously stated, edit the question and add the code there. Do not post it in the comments.

Comment: there is no code, that is what I'm trying to get

Comment: That is code or syntax or whatever you want to call it. Add it to the question so that it doesn't get lost in the comments. That makes it more likely that you'll get help. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should put you on track :

```
wordToPrint='hello'

echo "How many rows?"
read nbRows

echo "How many columns?"
read nbColumns

for ((row=0; row<$nbRows; row+=1)); do
    for ((column=0; column<$nbColumns; column+=1)); do
        echo -en "$wordToPrint\t"
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, worked like a charm! thank you so much